# How to get the value of related rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table like this:

```
// QandA
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+
| id | subject  | acceptedanswer | type | related | id_author |
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | subject1 | NULL           | 0    | NULL    | 123       |
| 2  |          | 1              | 1    | 1       | 452       |
| 3  | subject2 | NULL           | 0    | NULL    | 635       |
| 4  |          | 1              | 1    | 3       | 432       |
| 5  |          | NULL           | 1    | 1       | 246       |
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+

/* columns explanations:
- acceptedanswer can be NULL, 0, 1. (0 and NULL are identical). (it is NULL for questions)
- type is 0 for questions and 1 for answers.
- related is NULL for questions. For answers is containing the number of its own question
*/
```

Well I have two parameters:

- `id` number of an answer: `$id = 5`
- `id_author` of that answer `$id_author = 246`

Now I'm trying to get these two things:

- the subject of its owe question
- specifying has its own question any accepted-answer or not.

Here is my **query:**

```
SELECT t2.subject
FROM qanda t1
JOIN qanda t2 ON t1.related = t2.id AND t2.type = 0
WHERE t1.id = $id AND t2.id_author = $id_author
```

**Current result:**

```
+----------+
| subject1 |
+----------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+----------+---+
| subject1 | 1 |
+----------+---+
--           ^ this 1 means the question of this answer has a accepted answer
--           ^ this should be 0 if there isn't any accepted answer for that question
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the question answered by answer `id = 5` has an accepted answer, and assuming (as mentioned in comments) that each question can have only one accepted answer, then something like this (note: two joins) should work...

```
SELECT x.subject
     , y.id IS NOT NULL has_accepted
  FROM qanda x
  LEFT
  JOIN qanda y
    ON y.related = x.id
   AND y.type = 1
   AND y.acceptedanswer = 1
  JOIN qanda z
    ON z.related = x.id
 WHERE x.type = 0 
   AND z.id = 5;
```

Comment: This is wrong ..! As I mentioned in the question, I have an id of an answer ... you didn't use `$id` in your query at all.

Comment: Actually I figured it out .. I have to add that on where clause: `. . . where x.type = 0 and x.id = $id`

Comment: You know, your query works as well, just it is odd for me .. why your query works? I'm pretty sure I need two `join`s in this case. but yours works by one `join`. Just may you please add some explanations to your answer? Specially explain what's that `DISTINCT` and that note which is end of your answer ..

Comment: Ah I see +1. And no, having multiple accepted answers for one question isn't possible in my rules. So I don't need `DISTINCT`, right? Also what do you mean exactly of that note in your answer?

Comment: Actually my problem has been solved ..! Just for your information, your query needs two `join`s. Because you have the id of an **answer** ..! So one `join` finds its question, and other `join` checks accepted answer.

Comment: Ok, I guess you didn't understand my point ... all I have is this `$id = 5`. Ok can you give me both `subject1` and `1` *(there is accepted answer)* from the table *(which is in my question)* by one join?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.subject, max(COALESCE(t3.accepted, 0))
FROM qanda t1
INNER JOIN qanda t2 ON t1.related = t2.id AND t2.type = 0
INNER JOIN qanda t3 ON t1.related = t3.related
WHERE t1.id = $id AND t2.id_author = $id_author
GROUP BY t3.related
```

although, I am not sure if I understand your intentions. `COALESCE` to get rid of nulls, and `max()` to see if any of answers has been accepted. I am assuming that only answers have not-null values in `related` column.

Additionally, maybe it would be a better idea to not keep different things in the same table?

Comment: Just may you please tell me why did you use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I've assumed that you may have many answers per question, and you want to know if there is already an accepted answer for question of answer with `$id`. So you have one to many relation (between the answer you are interested in and all answers which you need to check), so you need to group.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you mean `GROUP BY` in query above is wrong *(useless)*?

Comment: You want to fetch information about the question, as `is answered` and subject are parameters of the question, not of the answer. You calculate `is answered` based on group of rows (all answers for some question), thus grouping is necessary.

Comment: The confusing bit is the fact, that you start from some particular answer, and you get question by it. You return some properties of the thing, by which you have to group, but it just happened, that you are not interested in the column, by which you are grouping (so ID/related), and you can't group by this, what you are returning/fetching (subject), as that one doesn't have to be unique.